# Problems submitting cordova .ipa after resigning

Tags: ios, iphone, cordova, build, codesign

I'm part of a team developing a Cordova application for iOS, the client has their own development profile and would like to submit the app under their own brand. To do this we have been archiving the build, then deploying the archive as ad-hoc and sending the resulting .ipa over to the company to re-sign and submit.

Within our own profiles we have been able to successfully validate the .ipa without any errors. However when the client re-signs they are getting the following error:

`ERROR ITMS-9000: "Missing Code Signing Entitlements. No enttitlements found in bundle 'com.XXXX.XXXX' for executable 'Payload/xxxxx.app/xxxxxx'."" at SoftwareAssets/SoftwareAsset (MZItmspSoftwareAssetPackage)`

I have put an entitlements file into the app, though it only has the "get-task-allow" key in it, within our application we are using push notifications, but I can't see anything that I need to put inside the entitlements to make that work.

The steps that I'm told the developer on the client end is following to re-sign the file are as follows:

1. Unzip ipa and remove code signature folder
2. Copy their own distribution provisioning profile into the payload folder
3. Replace the bundle id in the plist with the one they want to use and copy it to the payload folder
4. Sign the app using the codesign tool and their own distribution certificate
5. Zip the app back up into an .ipa
6. Submit the app in binary form

Any help or suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

There is absolutely no need to delete signature folder. You should allow the client to perform below steps.

1. Unzip .ipa file
2. Get .app file from payload
3. Resign the .app file using this [link](http://furbo.org/2008/11/12/the-final-test/). It is a command line exercise to perform.
4. Using this resigned binary (.app file) and their provisional profile, generate the .ipa file again.
5. Submit it to store.

I have done it for so many times and it works well. Hope it will help to you.